# Removing every non-digit character except a plus (+) sign in phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to alter a text string with a regular expression, removing every non-digit character,  except a + sign. But only if it's the first character

```
   +23423424dfgdgf234 --> +23423424234
   2344  234fsdf  9   --> 23442349
   4+4                --> 44
```

etc

The replacing of 'everything but' is pretty simple:
`/[^\+|\d]/gi` but that also removes the +-sign as a first character.

how can I alter the regexp to get what I want?

If it matters: I'm using the regexp in javascript's str.replace() function.

Comment: FYI, the `f` in `+23423424f234` isn't a digit. The `not any of these characters` regex is just `/[^\+\d]/g` (no need for being in case sensitive - we don't use any letters - are you trying to match an upper and lowercase `+`? :-) ). No need for the `|` character.

Comment: That f is a stupid typo. Not using the |-char is new to me....

Comment: The `|` should be used for words or *combinations* of characters. `(a|b)` could just be `[ab]` whereas `(foo|bar)` is **not** the same as `[foobar]` meaning (`f`, `o`, `b`, `a` or `r` or `(f|o|b|a|r)`). Trust me, if you wanted to try to find a way not to match a *word* you'd realize that it's a pain in regex. Also, the *or* (`|`) character must be used in `(..)`'s and not in `[..]`'s.

Comment: `Yourstring.match(/(^\+)?\d+/g).join("")`..

Comment: I have created http://jsperf.com/so-alter-string-with-regex for your convenience, if you want to play with and evaluate performance of the different approaches suggested.

Comment: What about "a+ + + +2bcdef3" string, would you expect 23 or +23 in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it in two steps, first removing everything that must be removed apart the `+`, then the `+` that aren't the first char :

```
var str2 = str1.replace(/[^\d\+]+/g,'').replace(/(.)\++/g,"$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the following regex

`[^\d+]` with `''`

and then on the resulting string, replace

`(.)\+` with `'$1'`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eT6uF6

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/QVd7R/2/

Comment: @thefourtheye. But the user wants to preserve the `+` in the front.

Comment: @VisioN, What problem do you face. You can see in the demo that it does work.

Comment: @VisioN, I have figured it out. Please see updated jsfiddle that I have provided in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do this in two steps:

```
// pass one - remove all non-digits or plus
var p1 = str.replace(/[^\d+]+/g, ''); 
// remove plus if not first
var p2 = p1.length ? p1[0] + p1.substr(1).replace(/\+/g, '') : '';

console.log(p2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the above suggested 2 replaces in a single RegExp:

```
var numberWithSign = /(^\+)|[^\d]+/g;
var tests =
    [
        {"input" : "+23423424dfgdgf234", "output" : "+23423424234"},
        {"input" : "2344  234fsdf  9"  , "output" : "23442349"},
        {"input" : "4+4"               , "output" : "44"},
        {"input" : "+a+4"              , "output" : "+4"},
        {"input" : "+a+b"              , "output" : "+"},
        {"input" : "++12"              , "output" : "+12"}
    ];
var result = true;
for (index in tests) {
    var test = tests[index];
    testResult = test.input.replace(numberWithSign,"$1");
    result = result && (testResult == test.output);
    if (!result) {
        return testResult + "\n" + test.output;
    }
}
return result;
```

Basically the first part `(^\+)` would match only the + sign in the beginning of the line, and will put it as `$1`, so when you replace this match with `$1` it will keep the plus sign in the beginning of the string. If it does not match, then the next part of the regexp `[^\d]+` will take effect, replacing all non-digits with an empty string (as there would be nothing in the value of `$1`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newString = Yourstring.match(/(^\+)?\d*/g).join("");
```

Comment: This fails on '+a+4', returning 4, instead of +4